# How do I delete a self closing html tag?

Tags: cursor-motions, filetype-html

I'm trying to delete self closing html tags, like the `img` tag below.

```
<div><img src='http://mypic.com/1.jpg' /></div>
```

I've tried `dit`, `dat`, the tpope/vim-surround plugin, and other things with no luck. I've also tried having my cursor in different places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for `da<` or `da>`?

- `d` deletes text (see `:help d`), and is followed by a motion movement (see `:help motion.txt`)
- `a<` or `a>` selections the text that starts with `<` and that ends with `>` (see `:help a<`)

If you want to delete the opening tag, the closing tag, and its content, then you can type `dat`. If you just want to delete the contents of the tag, you can `dit`.

Comment: Thank's for the quick response. That's perfect. I should have thought of it!